# I want to connect my mobile to system in office through reverse tethering

Tags: reverse-tether, micromax-yu-yureka

I am using Yu Yureka Mobile. I want to connect my mobile to system in office through reverse tethering. My Yureka Mobile was running on Cyanogen Mod 12.1 with Kernel version 3.10.49-cyanogenmod-gbca6118. Can anyone help me how to perform reverse tethering on my device?

Comment: Could you be a bit more descriptive? What "system in office" are you trying to connect it to?

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect your phone to the PC
2. Enable USB tethering from Settings>More (Wireless and Networks)>Tethering and portable Hotspot
3. Assuming a Windows computer in office, go to Network and Sharing Center
4. You should see two active networks, one from your ethernet and the other from your mobile phone (unidentified network)
5. Click on (Ethernet) Connections: *Local Area Network*
6. Properties
7. Click on the Sharing tab and enable the first option. Click Ok and you're done

This method will work well if your office does not use a proxy server to log in.